# How to pass data from the child component to the parent component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I can't seem to wrap my head around this emit thing, and hopefully today, I can make it clear. I have an array of rules, `this.rules` while I am inside RuleTable.vue component. When I clicked `Save` I need to submit the rules array to the back-end, and I don't have access to it. How do I pass my this.rules from my RuleTable.vue component to my create.vue parents component ?

[image]

Not sure if this helps, but my `this.rules` will look like this

```
[
  {
    "name": " one",
    "priority": 1,
    "url": "https://www.one.com",
    "details": [
      {
        "attribute_id": 1,
        "operator_id": 3,
        "value": "111"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: You can use `$emit` and in parent you can capture this event via `this.$on`

Comment: @RohìtJíndal where specifically, where do I add $emit in child component. Keep in mind the save button is located inside my parent component.

Comment: I updated my answer. Hope that will work as per your expectation now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In child component **:**

```
this.$emit('saveData', this.rules)
```

In parent component **:**

In script :

```
created() {
  this.$on('saveData', data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

--- OR ---

In template (In child component element) :

```
v-on:saveData="doSomething"
```

**Update :** As per your component structure, You are trying to access child component property `this.rules` from your parent component on `save`. If Yes, you can follow below steps **:**

- Use `ref` in your child component

  ```
  <parentComponent>
     <child-component ref="childComponentRef" />
  <parentComponent>
  ```
- Then access the variables or methods from child component in parent component on save.

  ```
  this.$refs.childComponentRef.rules;
  ```

Comment: what is `saveData` ? How is it going to trigger?

Comment: Where do I place those codes ?

Comment: `saveData` is just a name of the event. You can use any name. On save method you can trigger that `$emit` to pass the data to parent.

Comment: As you want to pass the rules array on click of save. You can put that first line of code inside this method and in parent you can capture that event in the `created` life cycle hook or you can access that in Html as well via `v-on:saveData="yourmethodname"`

Comment: I got the second part, what is line need to be at ? 

`this.$emit('saveData', this.rules)`

Comment: This line is responsible for emitting the `this.rules` to parent component from child component. Can you please have a look on this official documentation to understand it in better way https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

Comment: In child component : (but where ... )

Comment: The saveButton doesn't live in the child component, I don't know where to place the code.

Comment: This code `this.$emit('saveData', this.rules)`

Comment: ? Are you there ?

Comment: Sorry just now saw your messages. Tell me one thing When you want to pass the rules data from child to parent ? You should know about that.

Comment: @code-8 I updated my answer. Hope that will work as per your expectation now.

Comment: @code-8 Did you get a chance to look into this answer ? Just checking if this works for you or not